# body is not full screen

Tags: html, css, asp.net

The grey space is not used by my body. I want that part to be same background-color as body.

that's my css:

```
#body {
    background-color: #feffc0;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: try adding `html,body{height:100%;}` to your css.

Comment: you should also set the height of `html` to `100%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best practice of CSS is use a normalizator for all browser and default style.

I advice you to use this: [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Just add it to you code and all will work fine.

You problem is caused by the missing rule of body and html that you can find in normalize.css

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

and then **add this**:

```
body {
   height:100%;
   display:block;
   position:relative;
}
```

DEMO: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uLL10afc/)

Comment: it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: you have to add normalize.css and then create a new rule: body{height:100%;display:block;
  position:relative;}. if you do this it should work.

Comment: i did this and same behaviour.

Comment: You are welcome :).  (Approve the answare if you can).

Answer (score 1):

A couple things. First, you use the id selector for body, but I don't see that in your HTML, so I think you want to use just the html element selector.

To answer your question, use `height: 100%;`.

```
body {
    background-color: #feffc0;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the actual body of the page to have a height of 100%. Then you need to set the height of your main container to be 100vh.

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container (or#body or main or w.e your main container is called){
  height: 100vh;
}
```

See this  [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CZorio13/aduesp9L/2/) for an example